# SQL sub query counting numbers

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT b.PlateNumber, BusModel, Count(DISTINCT d.StaffID) AS NumberOfDirvers
FROM Bus b, Trip t, Driver d, Staff s
WHERE b.PlateNumber = t.PlateNumber 
AND t.StaffID = d.StaffID
AND d.StaffID = s.StaffID
AND b.capacity = 72
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.DateOfBirth) BETWEEN '07' AND '12'
GROUP BY PlateNumber, BusModel;
```

apparently there are some bus that hasn't got any trip with any drivers yet, but my code can't seem to show number of drivers as 0. how do i show it?

**Question:**

Given a bus capacity, say 72, find the set of buses that have the specified capacity.

For *EVERY* bus in the set, list:

- (i) the bus plate number,
- (ii) the model, and
- (iii) the total number of unique drivers who were born between the months of July to December and meanwhile have driven the bus (if there is no such driver, 0 is expected).

Comment: Consider providing some sample data and the desired result - ideally as DDLs and/or an Sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `IFNULL(value, 0)` to show `0` for no drivers found. Also you may like to enhance your query by using `JOINS`

```
SELECT b.PlateNumber, BusModel, IFNULL(Count(DISTINCT d.StaffID), 0) AS NumberOfDirvers
FROM Bus b LEFT JOIN Trip t ON b.PlateNumber = t.PlateNumber
LEFT JOIN Driver d ON t.StaffID = d.StaffID
LEFT JOIN Staff s d.StaffID = s.StaffID
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.DateOfBirth) BETWEEN '07' AND '12'
GROUP BY b.PlateNumber, BusModel;
```

Comment: where do i write in ifnull(value,0)?

Comment: @MuhammadHani . . . The `ifnull` is totally unnecessary.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` will return 0 if there are no matches.

Comment: the problem here lies with LEFT JOIN Staff s d.StaffID = s.StaffID as there are some bus who doesn't have any drivers... but how to get it set as 0 in the column number of drivers?

Comment: @MuhammadHani the problem here lies with LEFT JOIN Staff s d.StaffID = s.StaffID as there are some bus who doesn't have any drivers... but how to get it set as 0 in the column number of drivers?